# How to trigger event when clicking on a selected tab page header of a tab control

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

I am doing a Winform application in C# and I have some tab pages, say `tabPage1`, `tabPage2` and `tabPage3`, in a tab control, and `tabPage1` is selected.

I want to trigger event when **any tab page header is clicked**, but I could do it only for **page change** (by using `SelectedIndexChanged`) but not **click on a selected tab page header**.

I tried with `Selecting` and `Selected` events but both of them didn't not work. I searched on MSDN but didn't find any `Click` event defined on a page header. So how should I achieve this?

One further question, is it possible, and how, to detect `DoubleClick` on a **selected tab page**?

Comment: Does this have to trigger a post-back, or could you handle it with JS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the tabcontrol's MouseDoubleClick event.  You'll have to iterate the tabs to find out what specific tab was clicked:

```
    private void tabControl1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < tabControl1.TabCount; ++ix) {
            if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(ix).Contains(e.Location)) {
                // Found it, do something
                //...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Do keep in mind that this is completely undiscoverable to the user, he'll never think to double-click the tab.  You'll have to write a manual.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing your stuff on

> TabIndexChanged

If you want to load the contents on your 3rd tab, for example, handle the TabIndexChanged on your tab control, do a switch for each tabPage.Index and then do whatever is needed when user clicks on that tab.

Comment: do you mean `SelectedIndexChanged`? As I mentioned in my question, this didn't work because I didn't change the index, but click on the selected tab.

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void tabPage1_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
       //do something
    }
```