# Detect (right) click on tab page header

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I would like to show a contextmenustrip when I right-click a tab header.

[image]

However, I didn't find a way to detect a click on the tab header.

Does anybody know a way to do that?

Comment: take a look at this, you should be able to switch out mouse double click for checking for right click and it should work fine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478922/how-to-trigger-event-when-clicking-on-a-selected-tab-page-header-of-a-tab-contro

Comment: You would have to handle the appropriate event of the `TabControl`, call `GetTabRect` for each `TabPage` and see if any contained the mouse pointer by calling `Rectangle.Contains`.  You then show your `ContextMenuStrip` in the appropriate location with the knowledge of which tab it's being displayed for.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney Can you make your comment the answer?

Comment: It's not detailed enough to be an answer and I'm not willing to go to the effort to provide that much detail. Just do as I suggested and then post your own code as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Private Sub tab1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles tab1.MouseClick

    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.tab1.TabPages.Count - 1
        If Me.tab1.GetTabRect(i).Contains(e.X, e.Y) Then

            If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
                'Do some stuff here Me.ctxTabHeader.Show(e.X, e.Y)
            End If

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice answer. I'd recommend putting the button check as the outermost statement so that you only check once, instead of every loop.